# how to open page php wih a button in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a button and i want to open a php file who is in the same folder but it doesn't work. how i can do please. thi is the code

```
public function menu_html()
{
    echo '<h1>'.get_admin_page_title().'</h1>';
    echo "<p>Envoyez un nouveau message a un ou plusieurs clients</p>";?>
    <form method="post" action="Liste_contact.php"><input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Nouvelle campagne"></form>
    <?php

}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What *does* it do?  What is the resulting HTML that gets emitted?  How does it fail?

Comment: I mean, it does not open the php file "Liste_contact.php" entered Action

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the full URL to the file. Even if it is in the same folder the page that it's on is probably using a URL that is not representative of the folder structure. That is just how slugs work in Wordpress. For instance if this was in the root of a folder called my-theme I would use:

```
public function menu_html()
{
    echo '<h1>'.get_admin_page_title().'</h1>';
    echo "<p>Envoyez un nouveau message a un ou plusieurs clients</p>";?>
    <form method="post" action="http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/wpsms-market/Liste_contact.php"><input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Nouvelle campagne"></form>
    <?php

}
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT**

You would be using the following URL: example.com/wp-content/plugins/wpsms-market/Liste_contact.php. You would replace example.com with the root of your site.

That being said I don't think this is going to result in what you want. This file will not be loaded in your theme. I would use a shortcode to create the form in your theme and then another function in the plugin file to process the entry. I think you are going to need to change your entire approach.

Comment: What happens, do you get a 404? Doesn't work will not help anyone help you. If you use the URL you entered as the action right into the browser are you able to see the file? Can you tell us more about your folder structure?

Comment: yes i had an error 404. I am currently in the general.php file and I want the " new campaign " button opens the Liste_contact.php file. both php files in the same folder /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wpsms-market/

Comment: What are you waiting for?